# C#: Do I need to lock a static class when accessing from separate threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static-methods

I have a static class with a few methods that just take in a byte array, parses it, and returns a structure. I need to call these methods from many separate threads. Do I need a lock() or some kind of thread-safety within the methods? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: do your method use static variables?

Comment: the methods contains variables but they are not static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your method is [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_(subroutine)) you don't need any locks.

In general, you need locks whenever multiple threads access a shared resource. When the method just calculates something from its arguments without accessing any shared resource, there is nothing to lock.

Comment: by your definition, his example would *not* be re-entrant.

Comment: That's why I put an "If" in the beginning of my answer. From the description if his method I thought it was re-entrant, but I can't tell for sure without looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `lock` prevents multiple threads accessing the same data at the same time, which would lead to inconsistent / unpredictable behaviour usually.

Answer (score 0):

If your methods have shared resource then you need synchronize access to it. It your case there is no shared resource and therefore no need to lock anything.